# Java mock database connection

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, tdd, mocking

I want to test class with make db connection. Class that I want to test accept as param in constructor `Connection` class. I want to pass mock object to the constructor. Can you tell me good framework with example how to mock db connection?

Comment: You might be interested in this resource: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118933/what-elements-of-my-junits-should-i-mock

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [MockRunner](http://mockrunner.sourceforge.net), which has support for [JDBC](http://mockrunner.sourceforge.net/examplesjdbc.html). General mocking frameworks like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) will also work, but JDBC is a set of interfaces returning each other so hand-mocking will be hard. See for yourself: [How to stub/mock JDBC ResultSet to work both with Java 5 and 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919544)

However mocking JDBC is so brittle and verbose (no matter which tools you use) that I would either suggest abstracting JDBC access within some thin DAO layer (see *@duffymo* answer) or go for in-memory database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com).

See also:

- [Mock JDBC driver not worth it](http://jroller.com/MikeSlattery/entry/mock_jdbc_driver_not_worth)

Comment: http://mockrunner.github.io/ says in the site that is hosting the updated version pvi :)

Comment: The "Mock JDBC driver not worth it" link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

Connection is an interface. Any mocking framework will be able to mock it: [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/), [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/), ...

Mocking it isn't different from mocking any other Java interface.

Answer (score 4):

You can either use a mocking framework such as the ones mentioned in the above answer (I personally use EasyMock)
**OR** Create you own mock object:

```
class FakeConnection extends Connection{
       // Overrive all method behavious you want to fake.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't create a mock connection - it proves nothing, in my opinion.

I can see why you'd mock the repository/DAO itself after you've tested it fully with a live connection.  You'd give the mock repository/DAO to a service or other client because you've already tested it - no need to prove that it works until you do an integration test.

Comment: This comment is in  2020.. Lot of big organizations will have something called sonar scan which will expect the code coverage (test cases) and if your project is full of JDBC calls ,  you have no option other than ending up mocking the jdbc calls.

Comment: I know what sonar is. I disagree. You prove nothing by testing a mock. Mocks are meant to be passed to other classes once you’ve proven that the class works.

Comment: Agreed. But if you have to satisfy sonar and code coverage and if your organization needs it as a mandatory artifact to have atleast 75% code coverage , what option we are left with other than mocking the calls.  It's purely to satisfy sonar code coverage.

Comment: Big organizations tend to do things dogmatically, even if they make no sense.  I understand your requirement.  I'm pointing out that it's not smart.  Please carry on satisfying it.  You and others should understand that it's worthless.  You aren't increasing quality or guaranteeing correctness.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to reuse that mock on many test cases you can also consider implementing your own implementation of connection and to reuse that implementation everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

My Acolyte framework is useful for such purposes -> https://github.com/cchantep/acolyte .

With this lib you can create a connection instance for which you provide handler. Implementing handler, you are able to 'dispatch' query or update : producing resultsets or update count (or warning).